# Determine the nth highest values from a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows `lst = [[0.6,0.3,0.1], [0.2,0.4,0.3], [0.9,0.1,0]]` (only non negative values). What I would like to do is to calculate the nth-highest value (by multiplication), using one value from each sublist.

To get the highest value, you can simply take the maximum of each sublist and multiply them together to get the 1st highest value `0.6 * 0.4 * 0.9`. The 2nd highest value would be `0.6 * 0.3 * 0.9`. How would you create a function to do this?

I know there is the Viterbi algorithm for getting the best sequence, however, this problem is not the same as what is required for the Viterbi.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you wan to get a proper answer you should update your question with the codes that you've tried so far and tell us what's wrong with that.

Comment: Can you explain how the 2nd highest value is calculated. Is it by taking the second highest from each sublist and taking product ?

Comment: It's not always true that you just take the `max()` of each sub-list to get the highest product, if you have an even number of sub-lists and negative numbers

Comment: @Chris_Rands Doesn't even need to be an even number of sublists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate them, sort them, and pick the nth highest one.

```
>>> lst = [[0.6,0.3,0.1], [0.2,0.4,0.3], [0.9,0.1,0]]
>>> n = 2

>>> from itertools import product
>>> from functools import reduce, partial
>>> from operator import mul

>>> sorted(map(partial(reduce, mul), product(*lst)))[-n]
0.162
```

Answer (score -1):

Example with comprehension list:

```
lst = [[0.6,0.3,0.1], [0.2,0.4,0.3], [0.9,0.1,0]]
maximums = [max(x) for x in lst]
score = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, maximums)
```